# Python: why except is called even after exit

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please check the below code,

```
import sys
try:
    seq=eval(raw_input("Enter seq number: "))
    if seq <= 0 or seq >= 9999:
       print "Sequence number not in range [0001-9999]"
       sys.exit(1)
except:
      print "!!! Sequence number not in range [0001-9999]"
      sys.exit(1)
```

I gave a string to `eval raw_input` function.

```
$> python test.py
Enter seq number: "12"


Sequence number not in range [0001-9999]
!!! Sequence number not in range [0001-9999]
```

Why is it not exiting even after receiving `exit` call?

Comment: use `int` instead of `eval`. Use `except ValueError:` instead of bare `except:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sys.exit` just raises an exception (`SystemExit`), which is then caught. As a demonstration:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    sys.exit(1)
except:
    print "This threw the following exception:"
    traceback.print_exc()
# This threw the following exception:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
#     sys.exit(1)
# SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: @Dinesh: Be specific in your `except:` about what exception you are trying to catch. What are you trying to avoid? An `IndexError`? A `ValueError`?

Comment: You could also use `os._exit` to kill the interpretter right then and there -- but it's definitely not recommended :)

Comment: Just say "except Exception:" - bare "except:" clauses are problematic for just this reason. And the SystemExit exception that is thrown by sys.exit will not be caught by "except Exception:", so there is no extra excepting needed.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.exit` raises the `SystemExit` exception which is caught by your unnamed exception handler

Note, it is usually not a good idea to have a generic exception handler as its evident here.

So as to avoid catching the `SystemExit` with your generic exception handler, add another exception handler to handler your `SystemExit`

```
>>> try:
    seq=eval(raw_input("Enter seq number: "))
    if seq <= 0 or seq >= 9999:
       print "Sequence number not in range [0001-9999]"
       sys.exit(1)
except SystemExit:
    pass
except Exception:
      print "!!! Sequence number not in range [0001-9999]"
      sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: No! This is not correct! By adding "except Exception", you are already doing the right thing. SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt (to name two special exceptions) do *not* derive from Exception, so you do not need the additional do-nothing "except SystemExit:" handler. The OP's original problem was the bare "except:" handler, which catches everything, including SystemExit. Changing to "except Exception:" is the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent case why you should never use a bare except.  Invalid numbers are ValueErrors, so:

```
import sys
try:
    seq = int(raw_input("Enter seq number: "))
    if seq <= 0 or seq >= 9999:
       raise ValueError('sequence number not in range [0001-9999]')
except ValueError as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(1)
```

Output:

```
C:\>test
Enter seq number: 10000
sequence number not in range [0001-9999]

C:\>test
Enter seq number: abc
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'

C:\>test
Enter seq number: 5
```

Note `eval` is also frowned upon, because it will execute whatever the user types, such as `import shutil; shutil.rmtree('/')`.

Comment: `.rmtree('\\')` or `.rmtree('/')`